# snprintf - format not a string literal and no format arguments warning

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix, printf

I get `format not a string literal and no format arguments` warning when I compile it on Linux. [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) shows `const char*` for the third parameter. What is wrong to define  `const char *INTERFACE = "wlan0"` then pass it to the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    const char *INTERFACE        = "wlan0";
    struct ifreq ifr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), INTERFACE);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get any warning: http://ideone.com/BdSQF2 Seems to be OK

Comment: It is `const char *format` which seems like "%s"

Comment: What version of GCC do you have? (Run just `gcc -v` to find out).

Comment: I guess you might have a GCC older than 4.7; then it could be worth to upgrade your compiler.... (e.g. to GCC 4.8).

Comment: it is `gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)`, thank you for the hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing wrong (that's why it's a warning and not an error), it's just that the most common use of the `printf` family of function uses a *literal* format string.

Like:

```
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", INTERFACE);
```

In your case you should probably be using e.g. [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) instead:

```
#define MIN(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

memcpy(ifr.ifr_name, INTERFACE, MIN(strlen(INTERFACE) + 1, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
```

There's also [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) which might work, but there is a case when it will not add the terminating `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 4):

The latter part of the warning ("and no format arguments") means that the string doesn't contain any `%`s, and thus there is no point in using `snprintf()` like you're doing it.

It's worth warning for since it can be a security risk, if the string argument is changable at runtime it's possible that a `%` can be "snuck in", which will lead to problems. Therefore it's better if the formatting string is hardcoded to "do what you want".

As has been said, there's no point in using `snprintf()` in this case at all.

Comment: +1 for mentioning security risk. Idiomatic use (if you really must use snprintf) should be `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s", foo);`

Answer (score 1):

It is just a warning, so you could ignore it.

But it is not worth using `snprintf`  in your case, just code

```
  strncpy (ifd.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifre_name), INTERFACE);
```

this might run faster, and more importantly don't give warnings. If you want to be sure the name is null terminated, force it with `ifd.ifr_name[sizeof(ifr.ifre_name)-1] = (char)0;`

BTW, with the recent GCC 4.8, and compiling with `gcc-4.8 -Wall sven.c -o sven` I don't get any warnings. And even with `gcc-4.7 -Wall`. It might be a `libc` header issue in `<stdio.h>`...

Comment: Be careful that if the INTERFACE string is shorter than ifr_name, strncpy will add padding.