# snprintf - security risk

Tags: c, linux, security, posix, printf

The answer of [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011359/snprintf-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments-warning) leaded me another question. I used to ask question about

```
const char *INTERFACE        = "wlan0";
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), INTERFACE);
```

[unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind) replied as

> It's worth warning for since it can be a security risk, if the string argument is changable at runtime it's possible that a % can be "snuck in", which will lead to problems. Therefore it's better if the formatting string is hardcoded to "do what you want".

I wonder how is it possible to change the string argument on the runtime?

EDIT: to be clearer, could anyone give me an example how to change the string argument on the runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unwind` is no doubt referring to the `INTERFACE` variable.

If, for some reason you ask the user which interface they should use (using something like `fscanf()` into a writable buffer) and they enter `"wlan0 %s"`, all hell may break loose because you then have the situation where you're effectively executing:

```
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "wlan0 %s");
```

with *no* extra argument corresponding to the `%s` in your format string.

The way to protect against this is to use:

```
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", INTERFACE);
```

so that someone usurping `INTERFACE` will have no effect on that statement other than to change what's put into `ifr.ifr_name`.

In your particular case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    const char *INTERFACE        = "wlan0";
    struct ifreq ifr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), INTERFACE);

  return 0;
}
```

you remain totally in control of `INTERFACE` so there's no danger but the compiler is not doing that level of analysis - it just knows that a non-literal format string is a risk.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you correct me if I misunderstand you, the only way to change the string argument, `INTERFACE`, on the run time is that only if the program ask the user to enter a string value, otherwise it is not possible to do some hacker tricks then change the argument on the runtime

Comment: @sven, there are _many_ attack vectors, user input is one of them. There may be ways to attach to the process and modify its memory while it's running, or modify the strings in the executable file before it runs, or use input buffer overflow into a totally unrelated variable to affect INTERFACE. The possibilities are certainly more than you (or I) can think of alone :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: If someone can attack to the process and modify memory while the process is running then the process is already owned. That is not an attack vector.